# What is the meaning of delta squared?

Tags: finite-differences, chemistry

I know that $\Delta x = x_2 - x_1$. This is well known
Therefore, it follows that $\frac{\Delta a}{\Delta b}$ = $\frac{a_2 - a_1}{b_2 - b_1}$ (Unless I missed an elementary math class!)

Now, I found an equation in chemistry, while reading, that turns this principle on its head. It proposes that when considering the second in a set of values:
$\frac{\Delta^2 a}{\Delta b^2} = (a_3 - a_2) \times \frac{1}{\Delta b}$

My issue with this is that $a_3$ hasn't been measured yet, we have only $a_1$ and $a_2$ so how can this be?

Secondly, they propose this:
$\frac{\Delta \left(\frac{\Delta a}{\Delta b}\right)}{\Delta b} = \frac{\Delta^2 a}{\Delta b^2}$

Can anyone please help with the logic behind the first equation and algebra behind the second one?

Answer (score 1):

The expression $\frac{\Delta^2a}{\Delta b^2}$ is likely meant to be a finite difference approximation to the second derivative. The numerator is the *second forward difference*: $$\Delta^2 a_i=\Delta a_{i+1}-\Delta a_i=(a_{i+2}-a_{i+1})-(a_{i+1}-a_i)=a_{i+2}-2a_{i+1}+a_i.$$

Finite differences can be used to approximate derivatives. This is more usually done with a uniform step $h_x$ between sample points. Thus, a first-order approximation to a function’s second derivative using differences is $\frac{a_{i+2}-2a_{i+1}+a_i}{h_x^2}+O(h_x)$. Based on what you’ve written, the text appears to use $(b_{i+2}-b_{i+1})(b_{i+1}-b_i)=\Delta b_{i+1}\Delta b_i$ for the denominator instead in order to account for non-uniform sample spacing. The notation then appears to be simplified at the expense of making it more confusing by dropping the indices and combining the two differences in the denominator into $\Delta b^2$. Of course, if the $b$’s *are* uniformly spaced, then everything is peachy. Indeed, the equation $\frac{\Delta^2a}{\Delta b^2}=\frac{\Delta\left(\frac{\Delta a}{\Delta b}\right)}{\Delta b}$ only makes sense if they are.

The definition $\frac{\Delta^2 a}{\Delta b^2} = (a_3 - a_2) \times \frac{1}{\Delta b}$, on the other hand, doesn’t make sense to me. It seems like there’s something missing. The above expression for $\frac{\Delta^2a}{\Delta b^2}$ can be rewritten as $\frac{\Delta a_{i+1}}{\Delta b_{i+1}}\cdot\frac1{\Delta b_i}-\frac{\Delta a_i}{\Delta b_i}\cdot\frac1{\Delta b_{i+1}}$, which is suggestive, but doesn’t quite explain this definition.

Comment: $a_3$ and $a_2$ were arrived at by me, since we're considering the second in the set of values. A more general statement would be:

$(a_{i+1} - a_i) \times \frac{1}{b_i - b_{i-1}}$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\Delta \left(\frac{\Delta a}{\Delta b}\right)}{\Delta b}$ can only be calculated when there has been two stages of change.

First set of change is from (a$_{1}$, b$_{1}$) to (a$_{2}$, b$_{2}$) and second set of change occurs from (a$_{2}$, b$_{2}$) to (a$_{3}$, b$_{3}$).

Hence your first $\frac{\Delta a}{\Delta b}$$_{1}$ = $\frac{a_2 - a_1}{b_2 - b_1}$

and your second $\frac{\Delta a}{\Delta b}$$_{2}$ = $\frac{a_3 - a_2}{b_3 - b_2}$

So, your $\frac{\Delta \left(\frac{\Delta a}{\Delta b}\right)}{\Delta b}$ = $\frac{\frac{\Delta a}{\Delta b}_{2} - \frac{\Delta a}{\Delta b}_{1}}{b_3 - b_1}$

Now I believe that algebraic calculation and manipulation should lead you to the fact that RHS and LHS are same..

Comment: Perhaps I used a bad example. Let's say we had obtained a comfortable set of values and we're interested in solving the equation for the change from $(a_6, b_6)$ to $(a_7, b_7)$ and subsequently $(a_7, b_7)$ to $(a_8, b_8)$. The source of this equation would have me believe that I should use: $(a_9 - a_8) \times \frac{1}{b_8 - b_7}$... I believe the algebra would lead to $\frac{\frac{a_3 - a_2}{b_3 - b_2} - \frac{a_2 - a_1}{b_2 - b_1}}{b_3 - b_1}$ which results in $\frac{(a_3 - a_2)(b_2 - b_1) - (a_2 - a_1)(b_3 - b_2)}{(b_3 - b_2)(b_2 - b_1)(b_3 - b_1)}$...

Comment: how does that resolve to $\frac{\Delta^2 a}{\Delta b^2}$?

Comment: Actually now that tried to work it in a scratch paper.. I couldn't make the LHS and RHS equal in any form.. Sorry..

Comment: It's okay, thank you for your help nevertheless I appreciate it. Apparently the textbook author forgot to mention that this is actually differentiation and that he substituted d with $\Delta$, leaving the mathematically inclined to be want to divide by $\Delta b^2$ rather than taking it to mean simply second differential wrt b

Answer (score 0):

If you should ever come across this issue, know that this is really a matter of **differentiation** and not simply change. Admittedly, there is some overlap between the two but the $\Delta b^2$ in the denominator will throw you off if you do not know that it is simply a notation for "wrt b", and not a divisor